# Did I use Diodes and the Relays correctly in my Circuit Design?

Tags: diodes, switches, circuit-design, relay, bms

I'm a beginner and recently started a project where I build my own portable bluetooth speakers. I already have a rough layout of the whole thing. I basically want to power a 2x50 Watt Amplifier with two batterypacks wired in parallel.

Now I also want to be able to drive/charge it with a 120W Powersupply, but in a way where I can plug in the Powersupply and flip a switch to disconnect the batteries from the circuit, so the speakers don't draw power from them. If I were to not flip the switch, the powersupply should work as a charger, independent of if the device is on or not. For the Wires going into the Amp I couldn't find a DTDP Switch that could handle 100W-120W of DC Power, so I opted to use 2 Different relays to switch my circuits. I wanted to power them using the Powersupply when its plugged in, since thats the only time I would want to disconnect the batteries/ the battery chargers.

[image: my designed circuit]

**Now my questions are:**

**1.** Did I use the Diodes for the Relays correctly concering the Voltage Spikes that happen when you disconnect them?

**2.** Are the Diodes going from the Chargers to the batteries even necessary? My orginial thoughts were, since I use the same ports for charging and discharging I could use some Diodes to prevent the current to flow in the wrong direction, into my CC-CN charger. Do these already have protection or was this a good idea?

**3.** Are the Relays I selected fine for this usage? I will link the datasheets below.

[Google Drive download link to the 2 PDF Datasheets](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HrL_qexg77Jl4DYNA1jzOsilRRvAfor9/view?usp=sharing)

**If there are any other glaring mistakes I hope you guys can point them out to. Thanks in advance for the answers!**

Comment: Your schematic is very hard to read at that size. I can't tell which direction your diodes are pointing.

Comment: @Justme I have not built this thing. I am making sure first that the concept is sound. Why not though? As far as I know you only need a constant current and constant charge to charge the batteries, which these provide. My  BMS should take care of the the  balancing and the overcharge/overdischarge protection. Also could you elaborate why they need to be isolated?

Comment: @Hearth If you click on the picture it should get large enough to read.

Comment: @T.M I was wrong about the isolated, I was confused about the unclear wiring. Which exact modules you are using to charge batteries?

Comment: @Justme I wanted to use these DC-DC Buck down converters (https://www.amazon.co.uk/AZDelivery-XL4016-Parent/dp/B086XJ1KQQ) in junction with a 6S BMS (https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32955184179.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.4b0b4c4dsh1R06) I ordered on Aliexpress, of which I chose the 24V15A Seperate Port Version

Comment: I still think you are trying to charge lithium batteries dangerously without a proper charger. A buck converter is not a lithium chargrer. Even if the BMS has overcharge protection, it means that a failure has already happened during charging if the BMS needs to step in to protect the battery. Charging lithium batteries wrong is dangerous and can lead to explosion or fire.

Comment: @Justme I am aware of that danger. So what do you propose I should do? Is there a way for me to charge the batteries when I plug in a DC power source and dicharge them when permanently embedded in my Speaker? Thanks btw for the taking the time to help me!

Comment: Adding an appropriate charger board between the voltage source and the BMS is best practice IIRC.